# Refresh UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

Is it possible to refresh an UpdatePanel dynamically within a specify time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx) dedicated on this subject.